# Does Rails come with a "not authorized" exception?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncontroller

I am writing an application that uses plain old Ruby objects (POROs) to abstract authorization logic out of controllers.

Currently, I have a custom exception class called `NotAuthorized` that I `rescue_from` at the controller level, but I was curious to know: **Does Rails 4 already come with an exception to indicate that an action was not authorized?** Am I reinventing the wheel by implementing this exception?

**Clarification**: The `raise AuthorizationException` is not happening anywhere inside of a controller, it is happening inside of a completely decoupled PORO outside of the controller. The object has no knowledge of HTTP, routes or controllers.

Comment: well the http error code 401 means unauthorized, you could tell rails to return a 401 status code, and render whatever view you want

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady - I believe he's looking for sth like `raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')` which automatically forces application to render 404 without any rescue statmenets.

Comment: I usually just use devise + cancan, a nice combination for authentication and authorization

Comment: Agree with @MohammadAbuShady but, if you go that route, make sure it's CanCanCan since CanCan has been abandoned :)!

Comment: I didn't know that, I'll check, thanks for the info

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Rails doesn't seem to map an exception to `:unauthorized`.

The default mappings are defined in [activerecord/lib/active_record/railtie.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-1-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/railtie.rb#L25):

```
config.action_dispatch.rescue_responses.merge!(
  'ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound'   => :not_found,
  'ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError' => :conflict,
  'ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid'    => :unprocessable_entity,
  'ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved'   => :unprocessable_entity
)
```

and [actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/exception_wrapper.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-1-stable/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/exception_wrapper.rb#L8):

```
@@rescue_responses.merge!(
  'ActionController::RoutingError'             => :not_found,
  'AbstractController::ActionNotFound'         => :not_found,
  'ActionController::MethodNotAllowed'         => :method_not_allowed,
  'ActionController::UnknownHttpMethod'        => :method_not_allowed,
  'ActionController::NotImplemented'           => :not_implemented,
  'ActionController::UnknownFormat'            => :not_acceptable,
  'ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken' => :unprocessable_entity,
  'ActionDispatch::ParamsParser::ParseError'   => :bad_request,
  'ActionController::BadRequest'               => :bad_request,
  'ActionController::ParameterMissing'         => :bad_request
)
```

You could add a custom exception from within your application's configuration (or a custom [Railtie](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Railtie.html)):

```
Your::Application.configure do

  config.action_dispatch.rescue_responses.merge!(
    'AuthorizationException' => :unauthorized
  )

  # ...

end
```

Or simply use `rescue_from`.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I am curious how exceptions are mapped with Mongoid as the ORM.

Comment: @Stefan's link references a specific line number in `master` which changes over time.  Here's a more "perma" link to that code:  https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/v4.0.2/lib/mongoid/railtie.rb#L24

Answer (score 30):

I'm guessing the reason Rails didn't introduce this exception is because Authorisation and Authentication is not Rails native behavior (not considering basicauth of course).

Usually these are responsibilities of other libraries [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for NotAuthenticated; [Pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit), [Dude Policy](https://github.com/equivalent/dude_policy), [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan), Rollify for NotAuthorized) I would actually argue it may be a bad thing to extend `ActionController` with custom exceptions like `ActionController::NotAuthorized` (because like I said it's not it's responsibility)

So Way how I usually tackled this problem is that I've introduced custom exceptions on `ApplicationController`

```
class ApplicationController  < ActionController::Base
  NotAuthorized = Class.new(StandardError)
  # ...or if you really want it to be ActionController
  # NotAuthorized = Class.new(ActionController::RoutingError)

  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do |exception|
    render_error_page(status: 404, text: 'Not found')
  end

  rescue_from ApplicationController::NotAuthorized do |exception|
    render_error_page(status: 403, text: 'Forbidden')
  end

  private

  def render_error_page(status:, text:, template: 'errors/routing')
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: {errors: [message: "#{status} #{text}"]}, status: status }
      format.html { render template: template, status: status, layout: false }
      format.any  { head status }
    end
  end
end
```

Therefore in my controllers I can do

```
class MyStuff < ApplicationController
  def index
    if current_user.admin?
      # ....
    else 
      raise ApplicationController::NotAuthorized
    end
  end
end
```

This clearly defines that the layer your expecting this exception to be raised and caught is your application layer, not 3rd party lib.

The thing is that libraries can change (and yes this means Rails too) defining exception on a 3rd party lib classes and rescuing them in your application layer is really dangerous as if the meaning of exception class changes it brakes your `rescue_from`

You can read lot of articles where people are Waring about Rails `raise` - `rescue_from` being the modern `goto` (now considering anti-pattern amongst some experts) and in certain extend it is true, but only if you are rescuing Exceptions that you don't have full control off !!

That means 3rd party exceptions (including Devise and Rails to certain point). If you define the exceptions classes in your application, you are not relaying on 3rd party lib => you have full control => you can `rescue_from` without this being an anti-pattern.