# Bitpay Ruby client funtion error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bitcoin

Whenever I create an invoice using bitpay ruby client library fucntion

```
client.create_invoice(price: amount, currency: 'USD')
```

I get error like this

```
* BitPay::BitPayError Exception: Not authorized for facade: pos
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25892194/does-rails-come-with-a-not-authorized-exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select facade "pos" when pairing client.